# WebLogic 12.2.1.3.0 deployment issue (weblogic.application.naming.EnvironmentException: Unable to find injection target named)

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, weblogic12c, spring-roo

I've got an issue deploying a spring roo app onto WebLogic. Works fine in Websphere and Tomcat but WebLogic seems to be having difficulties. I've gotten the app deployed on a prior 12c weblogic instance before but don't remember which and exactly how. I've tried pretty much everything in weblogic.xml to reference preferred application packages that the app uses as well as library refs but it keeps giving me the following error for almost all classes:

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.application.naming.EnvironmentException: Unable to find injection target named: $interFieldInit$..._Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord$...$entityManager on class: class ..._Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.activate(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:123)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.activate(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:114)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:212)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:207)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.activate(ModuleStateDriver.java:57)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.activate(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:114)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:752)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:262)
at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:631)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:348)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:907)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1468)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:459)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:217)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:670)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
```

I can't find anything anywhere about that error and how to solve it. I wish it would be a bit more descriptive as to what it might need to make it run. If anyone else has had this issue, help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Spring configuration issue.

Integration features for WebLogic Server/Spring are deprecated in Oracle WebLogic Server as of version 12.2.1. Also, as of version 12.2.1, the Oracle WebLogic Server Spring console extension is not supported when using JRF or restricted-JRF.

For developing and administering Spring applications for Oracle WebLogic Server,refer below:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/wls/SPRNG/intro.htm#SPRNG288